# How to handle SSL/Let's encrypt with docker

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt

I am new to docker. I built a site with it using express/handlebars. I run the container and the system is up using unsecure http. How do I use SSL encryption using Let's Encrypt. What are my possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, HTTPS is handled by your reverse proxy.

The most common ones are [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/), [caddy](https://caddyserver.com/) and, particularly interesting in a container environment, [traefik](https://caddyserver.com/).
Caddy and Traefik have the advantage of automatically handling HTTPS certificates and even renewing them, if you settle on nginx, you'll have to use something like [certbot](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#alternative-1-docker) to refresh your certificates.